# loading tcl 8.4 dll

Tags: dll, tcl

I have a dll that my company has made which contains the company commands which we can use with our program.  The user interface created has the notebook tab feature which requires the use of Wish 8.6.  But the dll that we need to load has a dependency on Tcl84.  Is there anyway to either include Tcl86.dll as a dependency or get it so the program doesn't crash when it encounters this dependency issue?

Comment: I had the similar problem with XChat, I solved it by coping the tcl86.dll to tcl85.dll (in the same directory). Might be a hack, but at least it was easy and it worked.

Comment: If you can recompile the DLL, you could try to switch to the Tcl STUBS interface to gain version independence, so you can load if in 8.4, 8.5, 8.6 (just recompile using the oldest version supported and link against tclstubs84.lib instead of tcl84.dll, and do the proper stubs initialization in your DLL, see for a start: http://tcl.activestate.com/doc/howto/stubs.html ). If you cannot do that, its sheer luck if it doesn't crash. In theory you might be able to add some manifests to your DLL to have it load tcl84.dll while running in wish86, but that doesn't help you usually.

Comment: The problem is that Wish86 is dependent on Tcl86 and my dll is dependent on Tcl84.  When I renamed Tcl86 to Tcl84 it worked for a little bit and then it crashed.  Is there a way for me to modify my companies dll without the source code?  Or can I add the Tk feature from 8.6 into 8.4?